# how can i push array into other array where values match?

Tags: javascript

```
 var cols = [
      {id: 1, title: 'First Column', tasks:[] },
      {id: 2, title: 'Second Column', tasks:[] },
      {id: 3, title: 'Third Column', tasks:[] }
 ];

 var tasks = [
     {id: 1, title: 'Bla bla project', column: 1},
     {id: 2, title: 'Hip Hop project', column: 1}
 ]
```

How can i cycle through the tasks variable and push them into the cols array for the matching column id? is this possible without jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
cols.map(function(col){
  col.tasks=tasks.filter(function(task){ return task.column == col.id; });
})
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/t8wd0hmf/1/)**</kbd>